# Stopping a Running Cloud Functions Instance in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-run

Now that Cloud Functions (Generation 2) can run for up to 60 minutes, how do I stop a running cloud function **instance** (a specific invocation of the GCF)?

For example, what if I'm running a complex workload in many GCF invocation instances, and I need to stop one worker (e.g. I no longer need the output from that job), how would I stop just that GCF invocation instance?

Cloud Functions have an `labels.instanceId` value that appears in the logs. Is there an API to terminate an instance? The challenge here is that I can try listening for a kill signal (on a Pub/Sub subscription, or polling a GCS file, or listening to a Memorystore Redis Pub/Sub channel), but all of these won't scale well when running thousands of concurrent GCF instances that could potentially need killing.

It sure would be optimal if we could just tell the runtime (Cloud Run or Cloud Functions) to stop a specific running function invocation instance.

Comment: If your code (that runs in a Cloud Function) knows when there has been an error, it can just exit the function. The Cloud Function invocation ends and you stop paying for it. Not sure if this helps as I don't fully understand your use case.

Comment: No, you cannot directly stop any running instance. It will stop on error or sucess. The brute force method to stop it is deleting the function or deploying a new version.

Comment: Thanks, @Ferregina. Unfortunately, deleting the function isn't a valid solution for the use case, because there will be hundreds of other function instances running that need to continue to run. I need just the offending invocation to be stopped.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinOmander, I meant to ask you this last week in person. Let's say I'm using GCFs as service workers, for long running tasks. I need the ability to stop a worker sometimes, before it completes. However, I don't want to tear down the GCF, because I want other worker instances to complete. It sounds like there is no API for this and I'd need to handle my own messaging and function instance self termination?

Comment: No at this time. Maybe a Feature Request can be asked but in general those don't have an ETA :c

Comment: There isn't red button to stop all. You can remove all the permission of the Cloud Functions service account (I hope it is only dedicated to the function). You won't be able to stop the function, but you will isolate the code and stop any outside interactions.

Comment: Drive-by: this seems like a reasonable (feature) request (and applies to Cloud Run too). In other cases where a "thing" creates clones (Kubernetes Pods, MIG instances etc. etc.) there's usually a way to operate on a clone. A question for @joseph-lust: how would `gcloud functions instances` filter the clones to determine which need to be whacked?

Comment: @JosephLust, did any of the comments above address your concern? If so, please post an answer so that community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Comment: @JosephLust -- It was good to see you last week! It sounds like you're thinking of functions as long-running things, like virtual machines. Cloud Functions were built to run quickly and handle small units of work: convert one database record, translate one sentence, or send one message, and then exit. If you want to do 100 units of work, you invoke Cloud Function 100 times. I find this makes my code simpler as it's more in line with the vision of the folks who built Cloud Functions. Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

As stated from the comments above, there's no option to stop a running Cloud Functions instance as it will only stop on error or success. A [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) was also suggested from the comments however we don't have a specific ETA for this.